# Authenticate user's from facebook, google+ and LinkedIn as in http://klout.com/home for my iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, authentication

I am developing an iPad(objective C, iOS) application. In which I want the user to log in using either Facebook, google+  or linkedIn id. That is quite easy, but the problem is, when user enters the app using any of the id's. Where i want the user to be able to login to his remaining two accounts(Eg. Suppose Mr.X enters the application using his Facebook Authentications, he enters the app, now Mr. X wants to log in to his google+ and the linkedIn accounts). I have been googling this for long, but I am not able to find the solution. For example you can see the requirement in this website (http://klout.com/home), where it will ask for FB or twitter Authentications, once the user logs in, the user can connect to his rest of the accounts.

Thank's in advance...